# how to read single record in Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I use asp.net web api for reading data into my kendo grid. When user click on a cell, it changes to edit mode. What i am trying to achieve is that when it changes to edit mode, it should also get the latest record from the back end. is it possible by someting like:

```
 edit:function(e){ 
e.model.read();
}
```

Comment: If you want to read just one record you should use filter in the DataSource but that will likely refresh you Grid since this is an Observable Object. The _solution_ would be send a request (using ajax) to the server for getting the data. But why do you need to read it from the server and not from the DataSource?

Comment: Hi OnaBai, thanks for your response. My requirement is like if someone has opened a form for a long time and by the time something is changed in the underlying database, I need to reload that data into this record.

Comment: basically you need to update the grid and only then allow enter in edition mode, right? or that would be a too heavy call?, i.e. update the grid is a slow request?

Comment: Did you realize that `edit` event is actually fired after entering in edit mode? Whatever you do for refreshing the row will imply exiting edition mode, update value with the data coming from the server and then entering edition mode again. And having a strong RealTime background I would say what about if while doing this is when the server actually gets updated? You cannot be sure about it... Even going further, what about if the row is updated while you are editing it? No solution for it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do what you want but remember that despite you get the data from the server remember what I said in the comment to your question:

> Did you realize that edit event is actually fired after entering in edit mode? 
>   Whatever you do for refreshing the row will imply exiting edition mode, update value with the data coming from the server and then entering edition mode again. 
>   And having a strong RealTime background I would ask you:
>   * What about if while doing this is when the server actually gets updated? You cannot be sure about it...
>  
>   * Even going further, what about if the row is updated while you are editing it?

Said that, here it goes:

The basic trick is if you are editing a cell because the user clicked on it, then I'm going to send a read request to the server and cancel the edition. As consequence of the new read, I'm going to have a new `dataBound` event where I will ask if this is as consequence of this forced read and if so, I will enter in edition mode for the same cell.

This is the code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editingCell: -1,
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
        ...
    ],
    editable: "incell",
    edit:function(e){
        if (this.options.editingCell >= 0) {
            this.options.editingCell = -1;
        } else {
            this.options.editingCell = this.tbody.find("td").index(e.container);
            this.dataSource.read();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {
        if (this.options.editingCell >= 0) {
            this.editCell($("#grid td:eq("+ this.options.editingCell + ")"));
        }
    }
});
```

And a code snippet on this following (instructions, open it twice and play with one and the other and you will see that when enter in edition mode, it actually gets closed, refreshed and edited again). Remember to click on "Save changes" for sending the changes to the server.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service";
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read:  {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false
      },
      update: {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
        dataType: "jsonp"
      },
      parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
          return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
        }
      }
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 5,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
          ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
          ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
          UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editingCell: -1,
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: {
      buttonCount : 2
    },
    toolbar: ["save"],
    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Stock", width: "120px" }
    ],
    editable: "incell",
    edit:function(e){
      console.log("edit", this.options.editingCell);
      if (this.options.editingCell >= 0) {
        this.options.editingCell = -1;
      } else {
        console.log("forceRead");
        this.options.editingCell = this.tbody.find("td").index(e.container);
        this.dataSource.read();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {
      if (this.options.editingCell >= 0) {
        this.editCell($("#grid td:eq("+ this.options.editingCell + ")"));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#grid {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```